# Android Studio cannot recognize .ttf files

Tags: android, android-studio, fonts, android-studio-3.0, android-fonts

I am trying to import font files to my project. But Android Studio doesn't recognize the files I imported.

[image]

I can open these files outside Android Studio but Android Studio doesn't read them as fonts. Any reason for this?

Comment: how are you reading them inside Android Studio, you should always share some code

Comment: @FahedYasin I can't access it through code because Android Studio doesn't recognize the files as fonts in the first place.

Comment: have you tried cleaning or invalidate cache and restart option ?

Comment: `this happens when you dint add those files in git` !! if you are using..

Comment: try renaming font to fonts and put this folder in assets folder. if it still does not recognize it, no problem, just try with your code

Comment: @FahedYasin please view my answer. I already fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: @Umair tried that and it didn't work. Please view my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried playing with Android Studio settings and found out that `.ttf` was not registered as a pattern for fonts. I just added `*.ttf` and it finally worked.

[image]

Comment: just for other people: you can add *.ttc there and Android Studio will understand that it is a font too

Answer (score 3):

Use **assets** folder instead of font

Comment: I am using fonts in XML and not the old way of importing fonts. Please refer to this link: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml

Comment: ok, you can use font inside of assets folder for xml. I have used in my project

Comment: yes, I have tried that in my old projects. Thank you.